# Principle of least privilege: Does Authbind helper really need setuid root, or can it run with cap_net_bind_services?

Tags: linux, setuid, capabilities, authbind

Does Authbind's helper really need setuid root, or can it run with the CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICES capability and still work?

Comment: Yet another missing tag; someone with enough privileges, please tag this with "authbind"

Comment: We have ~36K Q's on the site and this is only the 2nd instance that has ever mentioned `authbind`. I've never even heard of this and I've been in the business for 20+ years so it's hardly a surprise that this tag doesn't exist. This is similar functionality to `capabilities` which is pretty widespread.

Comment: Wow.  Yeah, the concept behind `authbind` is similar to that of capabilities, but `authbind` existed before the support for capabilities in Linux... or so the Wikipedia article says. :)  Unfortunately, Linux capabilities are a bit too ...  /damaged/ for me to use directly.  Combining authbind and capabilities, however, seems like the best of both worlds: I get to set permissions by uid (authbind) and I don't need set(e)uid root.

Comment: I was probably more so surprised than you when I searched our site and didn't find but 2 references, including yours. In reading the wikipedia page it made sense and I've usd capabilities myself, but am a new Debian user so has taken aback that something like that had slipped through the cracks.

Comment: Anywhoo, so in reading about it, it sounds like you have to have setuid to make it work.

Comment: I'm thinking the helper process need not be set[e]uid; the only special privilege it needs is the service socket binding one.  I'm currently experimenting with doing that, and it *seems* like that works.  I'll have to do some more experiments to confirm, and possibly look at the source.

Answer (score 0):

I found this excerpt in this thread titled: [Bind to ports less than 1024 without root access](http://serverdown.ttwait.com/que/268099).

*excerpt*

> I dimly remember a library called "authbind" that does what you need, by wrapping the `bind()` system call (via a `LD_PRELOAD` library), and, if a privileged port is requested, spawning a setuid root program that receives a copy of the file descriptor, then verifies the application is indeed permitted to bind to the port, performs the `bind()` and exits.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/268099/bind-to-ports-less-than-1024-without-root-access | From the actual Stack Exchange site

Comment: @user314104 - ha, that's funny, I thought the posts in the thread looked like a SE site but didn't think to search for the quote to find it. Nice sleuthing.